# C# DataGridview with condition in cell event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a small project with the once DataGridView and one if condition. This is an Datagridview and with two columns

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUS5U.jpg

In datagridview when you editing the first row in datagridview it's creating new rows. Like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJzlC.jpg

I know way to disallow user to add new rows and make it programmatically but I don't need this way

I write this code. this is ex. condition

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender,  DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        string no = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        if (no == "1")
        {
            dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex + 1, e.RowIndex].Value = "john";
        }
}
```

It's working to adding data. I need if the no variable its not equal 1 still focus in the same cell and not going to next row

I add this code

```
  else
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

            }
```

and still go down ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish here… if the user types a “1” in a cell, the cell to its right has some text added to it? I am guessing you may want to look at the `CellValidating` event or `CellValueChanged`?

Comment: As far as “returning” to the previous cell… If the user, clicks, tabs or cursors “away” from a cell… the `CellEndEdit` event will fire “before” the UI actually moves to the next cell. Meaning that the line of code in the `else` clause: `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];`  is ineffective since the `CurrentCell` hasn’t moved yet.

Comment: It is challenging to go back to the previous cell because there is no info about “where” the next cell is when leaving and vice versa… when you get to the next cell (enter) … there is no info about “where” the previous cell was. It sounds like you need to “Cancel” the event and not let it move to the next cell, that’s what `CellValidating` can do.

Comment: Thank you johnG.  Be short I want if the no var not equal to 1 stay in the same cell .. that's